# MVC 3 Controller Action Return Localized Strings in JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, localization

I am currently working on a product of ours that is an MVC 3 based project. The product was recently slated for launch in Canada where there are laws requiring all websites to provide both English and French versions of the copy.

The basic architecture consists of:
- A loclaization class library
- The MVC3 application
- A DAL 
- All controllers inherit from a base localizable controller class that sets the current thread's CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture to the proper language. This is working great (borrowed from Scott Hansel's code).
- Also it has a basic REST API that called via jQuery from the UI.

I have all the Views working as desired but I am having issues in getting the action to return the proper language for messages. The API controller actions do not return ActionResults instead they return a JSON string. I do not believe this to be the culprit of my pains though.

I am currently trying to leverage the ResourceManager object with no luck. Here is the latest code I have tried.

Note that CultureName is a property provided by the BaseLocalizableController object.

```
var rm = new ResourceManager("ProductXYZ.Localization.App_GlobalResources.Messages", Assembly.Load("ProductXYZ.Localization"));
viewModel.Message = rm.GetString("SuccessfullySaveChanges", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(user.Language ?? CultureName));
```

The GetString function is always returning English, event when it should be returning French. I know that there is something fundamental I am missing here, but just haven't been able to locate it and I am now up against a hard deadline.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

ADDITIONAL INFO *************

I am working in Visual Studio 2012

Comment: What does user.Language return? (Set a breakpoint and check it please.)

Comment: it is correct fr-CA for French and en-US for English. Both resource files are fully implemented and pair one another.

Comment: So if you manually enter the string "fr-CA" it doesn't return the right value? Only one conclusion, there's something wrong with your resources.

Comment: That is correct. Works correctly when rendered out at the View just not inside of controller actions. This leads me to disagree with your conclusion.

Comment: In programming when accessing non mutable data, the general rule is that wherever you execute the same code, the results are the same. With other words, there has to be a difference in either code or state. The only state I know of when it comes to resources is the `CultureInfo`. Therefore I recommend **not** making the `CultureInfo` every time, but assigning it to the thread after authentication. See my answer for that.

Comment: Agreed. I am just running tests to figure what heck is going on. Never performed this specific task before. Only worked with localized views which are very straight forward. Though I thought this would be also.

Answer (score 0):

If your architecture is correct in your application, then using `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` and `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` should be set to French (in case you're on the French site).

If this is not the case, you should handle this in your Global.asax, this could be done through:

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(HttpContext.Current.User.Language ?? CultureName);
    Thread t = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread;
    t.CurrentCulture = ci;
    t.CurrentUICulture = ci;
}
```

After doing this every function that uses globalization will function according to the proper culture. (This also includes for example: `(5.52M).ToString()`, which'll then depending on the culture result in `5.52` or `5,52`.

One important step is to change the line:

```
viewModel.Message = rm.GetString("SuccessfullySaveChanges", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(user.Language ?? CultureName));
```

To:

```
viewModel.Message = rm.GetString("SuccessfullySaveChanges");
```

Comment: I do not see any change whit sticking the Culture setting code inside of the Application_PostAuthenticateRequest function.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Another interesting item is that the base response object is showing the correct format provider (fr-CA) in this test.

Comment: Then you might want to double check your spelling of `"SuccessfullySaveChanges"`, because I'm not aware of anything else influencing this.

Comment: The first part is near identical to what I did. I removed the CultureInfo call in the GetString. But still have the same result.

Comment: This is what a break point in the ExecuteCore function showed. Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
    {fr-CA}
    calendar: null
    Calendar: {System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar}
    CompareInfo: {CompareInfo - fr-CA}
    compareInfo: {CompareInfo - fr-CA}

Comment: I am beginning to question if this is a bug in VS2012

Comment: @Mike Honestly, I wouldn't be surprised, the other day we had a weird bug that on 10% of the systems that had VS2012 installed, an exception would silently unhandled in a WinForms application. But if bound an empty event handler to [Application.ThreadException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx) it'd all of the sudden catch it right at the place where the exception was thrown.

Comment: I will keep digging and if I find something I will come back and post it. Thank you for you assistance and insight today!

Comment: @Mike Anytime, but this problem is theoretically impossible. Practically, apparently not :/ sadly